# Removing edge that causes a cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph-theory

I have a graph that is represented by an adjacency matrix, `G` and I am trying to use DFS to remove an edge that causes a cycle

There can be multiple cycles, but I figure it is probably best to remove them one at a time, so I only need my algorithm to find one cycle, and that can be repeated.

Here is the code for what I have got so far:

```
function [ G, c_flag, c_stack, o_stack, cptr, optr ] =...
    dfs_cycle( G, curr_v, c_stack, o_stack, cptr, optr, c_flag )

    % add current vertex to open list
    optr = optr + 1;
    o_stack(optr) = curr_v;

    % find adjacent vertices
    adj_v = find(G(curr_v,:));

    for next_v = adj_v
        % ensure next_v is not in closed list
        if ~any(c_stack == next_v)
            % if next_v in open list then cycle exists
            if any(o_stack == next_v)
               % remove edge and set flag to 1
               G(curr_v, next_v) = 0;
               G(next_v, curr_v) = 0;
               c_flag = 1;
               break;
            end

            [G, c_flag, c_stack, o_stack, cptr, optr] =...
                dfs_cycle(G, next_v, c_stack, o_stack, cptr, optr, c_flag);

            if c_flag == 1
                break;
            end

            % remove vertex from open list and put into closed list
            o_stack(optr) = 0;
            optr = optr - 1;
            cptr = cptr + 1;
            c_stack(cptr) = next_v;
        end
    end
end
```

the function is called using:

```
v_list = find(sum(G)>0);
o_stack = zeros(1,numel(v_list));
c_stack = o_stack;
optr = 0;
cptr = 0;
root_v = v_list(randperm(length(v_list),1));
c_flag = 0;
[G_dash,c_flag,~,~,~,~] =...
    dfs_cycle(G, root_v, c_stack, o_stack, cptr, optr, c_flag);
```

It should return the modified (if cycle found) adjacency matrix, `G_dash` and c_flag corresponding to whether a cycle was found or not.

However, it doesnt seem to be functioning as it should.

I think I have located the problem; in the line `if any(o_stack == next_v)` it will return true, because the previous vertex visited is usually still in `o_stack`, however I am not sure how I should go about fixing this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A connected, un-directed, acyclic graph is called a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), with n nodes and n - 1 edges. For a formal proof, see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196898/how-can-you-prove-an-acyclic-graph-has-n-1-edges).

So, to form a tree from your graph, you just need to run DFS once, and keep all edges used by this DFS (for more information about tree created by DFS, see [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), example section). Those unused edges can be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfectly for what i wanted!